# Could not find property ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

I have take over an Android Project, and unfortunately I don't know which SDK version and Android Studio version it was built with.

However, most code compiles fine, except that I get a complaint about a missing property, ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION, in build.gradle.

Is this some property that was defined in earlier SDKs and was removed now, or is there some other way of defining this property now?

Of course I could just add it to get rid of the compiler error, but I would like to know why this happens.

This is what the relevant section looks like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Comment: buildToolsVersion '23.0.2', minSdkVersion 12 //change as per your need targetSdkVersion 23 try it

Comment: The question was about the property ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION, not which version I should compile with/for.

Comment: buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this some property that was defined in earlier SDKs and was removed now

No.

> or is there some other way of defining this property now?

You can define it in your `gradle.properties` file, in the top level of this project. Ideally, you define it in the same place where `ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION` and `ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION` are defined, as those too are something custom that your predecessor did for this project.

Comment: Since I have the whole dev tree, where could these properties have been defined before?

Comment: @PeterAndersson: There is a syntax for putting them in environment variables, but those will not work in Android Studio, last I checked. There is a syntax for putting them in command-line switches, which would have required custom build rules in Android Studio (and a shell script/batch file for command-line builds). I can't rule out them being defined up in your top-level `build.gradle` file, but the approach that I usually see for that involves `ext`. I can't think of another way to do this off the top of my head.